# JavaFX vs. Swing

Tags: java, javafx, swing, swt

Давненько не брал в руки шашку, как то решил переписать свою аппу под Android на толстого десктоп клиента и обнаружил, что Swing типа как бы умер...

Ну по крайней мере теперь все мануалы рекомендуют быстренько пересесть под JavaFX

Мануалы, мануалами, но жизнь как известно живет своей жизнью. Откликнитесь разработчики которые пишут толстые desktop клиенты. На чем пишете, правда ли что теперь надо пересаживаться под JavaFX, какие это дает преимущества или наоборот в чем боль?

Правда ли что клиент под JavaFX легко можно подстроить под браузерного клиента или это маркетинг не более того?

В общем поделитесь жизненной правдой.

Comment: да лучше использовать FX чем Свинг, как минимум fx совместим со свингом, кстати вот это тоже интересно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586939/javafx-in-enterprise-web-applications-good-alternative-to-classic-web-pages

Comment: Комментарий оставить не могу, поэтому отпишусь тут. Сам я только ученик и мало что еще понимаю в разработке, но один знакомый на мой взгляд хороший программист сказал, что новое ПО как правило никогда не пишется уже на Swing (так как технология устарела), но и JavaFX прям уж кардинально нового в себе ничего не несет, поэтому старое ПО как правило на FX не переписывают. На остальные вопросы не отвечу, надеюсь хоть немного помог. Удачи!

Comment: Можно нарисовать в webEngine html+js и пробрасывать события из и в него, если это подразумевалось под подстройкой браузерного клиента